# What does dead.letter files do

Tags: files

I find dead.letter files from time to time in my `$HOME` directory. What they are for?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Either a program tried to send mail and failed (this is more likely), or you were in the middle of writing mail and broke out, so the client saved the draft in `dead.letter`. From the `mail` man page:

> Normally, when you abort a message with two interrupt characters (usually control-C), mail copies the partial letter to the file dead.letter in your home directory.

Comment: Why its size is usually 0 bytes?

Comment: @Micheal Mrozek can i do something like that dead.latter file will never generate, even program tried to send mail has failed ?

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore: According to the man page you can prevent this behaviour by adding the word/command `nosave` to the line starting with the `set` keyword in `/etc/mail.rc`. I have not tested this yet however.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an alert for my HDD death :'(.

It's still good to know what happened by reading the content of the file.

More info are available on the file it self.

Comment: The same is true for me. I see a lot of SMART warnings and failed mounts for drives lol