# What process is generating dead.letter?

Tags: cron, email

I'm using linux:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I noticed a few weeks ago that there is a file in my home directory: `dead.letter`.
The file is updating at the first second of every minute with the same number of log line.

I have been searching for the process that cause this over a week for now and still can't find it.

I've tried https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-process-file-is-busy +
`auditctl`, killing and uninstalling docker, verifying multiple location where cron jobs may be. Disabling the cron process.

+ mail sendmail and mailx commands are not recognized.

I can't find the process that causes this.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/what-does-dead-letter-files-do

Comment: Or this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/851629/what-does-this-dead-letter-file-talking-about-a-smart-warning-mean

Comment: do you have a cronjob that runs every minute?  What does `cron -l` show?  cron will attempt to mail on behalf of the user if there is stdout or stderr.  If you add `> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` to a cronjob it will not have any output to attempt to mail.

Comment: @toppk
I have one job but it is not the job that generates the files.
Even when commenting it out and even shutting down the cron service the file still getts updating.

Comment: @QuartzCristal I already looked at both these threads. Sadly I still haven't to resolve the issue.

Comment: If there are more than one user (at minimum: root and you), you should check the cron entries for all those users. In specific, there is a `/etc/crontab` with root privileges and (at least) one crontab file per user inside `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. Do not edit this files directly, use `crontab -l` while logged in as an user to see the crontab of that user and execute `sudo crontab -u root -l` to list root crontab (or crontab -l while logged in as root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:
We use nfs mounts in our organization. We also use AWS.

We created a new instance from an ec2 instance I was working on.
The template instance had a cron job, that kept running on the new instance, and writing data to the shared directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can give it what it wants, by installing mailx/sendmail, or just create a simple fake in /usr/bin/mailx

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" > /tmp/mailx.$$.args
pstree $$ > /tmp/mailx.$$.pstree
env > /tmp/mailx.$$.env
cat > /tmp/mailx.$$.cat
```

hopefully it will fall for the trick and you can see whats in /tmp/mailx.*   maybe that will help discover the source.  The other option is to use something like bcc/bpftrace but getting that to work on old ubuntu may be too difficult.

Another trick would just to put a sleep 20 inside the /bin/mailx script and use that time to do a pstree and find the calling process.